# StreamReader is missing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, streamreader

is there something that I can do to amend this?

> A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces;
>   'System.IO.StreamReader' is a type not a namespace

Looking into "add a reference" and the StreamReader is not available in the list of options available for selection.

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.StreamReader;
```

Comment: Are you trying the new C# 6 features? In previous C# versions, using is reserved for namespaces.

Comment: It´s C#, not *Java*: `using System.IO` is allowed and `using System.IO.StreamReader` is not

Comment: @GrantWinney It's valid in C# 6 ;)

Comment: You can let VS manage using's for you: Right click on code underlined in red -> Resolve -> using ... (works only if you have assemblies referenced)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System.IO;
//THATS TOO MUCH : using System.IO.StreamReader;
```